# Add OR, with beta/log(OR), and SE in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I want to add OR before log(OR) in the table below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

dat <- 
  iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") 
  
glm(Species ~ ., family = binomial(), data = dat) %>% 
  tbl_regression() %>% 
  modify_column_hide(columns = ci) %>% 
  modify_column_unhide(columns = std.error)
```

[image]

Any idea or it's not possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `modify_table_body()` to add a new column with the OR. Once the new column has been added, you'll need to add a column header and indicate a function  to style/format the new column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.2'
dat <- 
  iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") 

tbl <-
  glm(Species ~ ., family = binomial(), data = dat) %>% 
  tbl_regression() %>% 
  # add OR to `.$table_body`
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate), .before = estimate)
  ) %>%
  # style new column with header and formatting function
  modify_header(estimate_exp ~ "**OR**") %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(estimate_exp ~ style_sigfig) %>%
  # hide CI and show SE
  modify_column_hide(columns = ci) %>% 
  modify_column_unhide(columns = std.error)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>